# QnAmaker, can't find Channels tab

Tags: azure, service, bots, azure-qna-maker

I deployed my QnAmaker chatbot using the new GA QnAmaker portal today. But after creating the knowledge base, i can't find the channels tab in Azure anymore.

In the channels tab, you could deploy the chatbot to different channels like Microsoft Teams or the Webchat.

Has anyone found this tab in Azure?

Comment: QnAMaker is a product, Bot Framework (Web App Bot, Functions Bot...) is another. Can you add more details of what you did when you say "deployed using the new GA QnAMaker portal"?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, i created a new knowledge base on the new QnAmaker portal. You now have to create a QnAmaker service in Azure first. After i did this and finished setting up the knowledge base, the following resources were deployed
https://imgur.com/a/1vgvwaM

In these resources, i can't find any options to deploy the bot to a specific channel (webchat or Microsoft Teams).

Comment: Ok so that's what I thought: you are mixing both services. Here you just have created a QnAMaker Service, that is to say an API able to generate answers. To use it in a bot, you need to create a bot and point to this service

Comment: Hi Nicolas, how can i do that exactly? It used to be quite easy to create a bot without any coding involved

Comment: I'm preparing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just created **your QnAMaker knowledge base** and all the necessary items to use it (web app to host the service, Azure Search for the search part).

Now the next step is to **create a bot** by doing the following:

1. On Azure, create a `Web App Bot`

   - Use `Question And Answer` bot template in order to have the basic code to call QnAMaker already implemented

[image: Creation sample]

2. Once it is created, you will have at least the following resources: one Web App bot (to manage channels) and one App Service (hosting your bot code)

[image: created resources]

- Go to the Web App Bot item
- Select `Application Settings` menu, you will found several settings: `QnAKnowledgebaseId`, `QnAAuthKey` and `QnAEndpointHostName`
- Fill those values with your QnA settings:

  - `QnAKnowledgebaseId`: it's your knowledge base Id on QnaMaker.ai website
  - `QnAAuthKey`: it's the Authorization EndpointKey value on QnaMaker.ai website (check https://www.qnamaker.ai/UserSettings)
  - `QnAEndpointHostName`: the endpoint location where you published your KB (also visible on https://www.qnamaker.ai/UserSettings)
- Save

Then it's working ;-) and you can set the channels you want on the `Channels` menu of this Web App Bot item

Comment: You are a hero! Thank you very much. It works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It's still there. QnA MAker going GA has no impact on its functionalities but the way of implementation to some extent, which is of course in a good sense.

You Can find it on Azure Portal => Web App Bot => Bot Management section

Happy Coding!